# How to fix linker error "cannot find Scrt1.o" without Internet? Linux Mint

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-mint

I installed linux mint 21 x64 on a virtual machine.  I created an empty project in VS Code, which contains 3 files: launch.json, task.json, main.c.  Main.c has simple code.
Next, I try to compile this file "gcc -g main.c -o main" and get the error:

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory`
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

How can I solve this problem **without** using apt-get install since there is **no Internet** on my PC?

Comment: Why are you not installing it from hand?

Comment: You haven't installed all the packages needed to build C programs, apparently, so the answer is still "install them".  How to do it without internet access is more a question of system administration than programming, so not really on topic here, but you can download the `.deb` files on another machine and copy them over by flash drive or similar, then install manually with `dpkg -i`.  Or install a tool like `apt-offline` by that method and then use it to streamline the process.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, the problem is in the installation without the Internet.  Thanks, I'll try to figure it out based on your information.

Comment: @samann I found the multilib package to solve the problem, but I don't know how to install this package manually.